# Insertar datos desde SQL server a struts2

Tags: java, jsp, jdbc, batch, struts2

Hola buenos noches a todos, les explico mi problema estoy realizando un insert a mi tabla :
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero esto es lo que se guarda en la bd : [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el resultado que busco desesperad amente es este : [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

les proporciono mi clase entidad :

```
public class CoordenadasP {


String CordNort;
String CordSurr;

public CoordenadasP(String CordSurr, String CordNort ){


    this.CordNort=CordNort;
    this.CordSurr=CordSurr;
}


public CoordenadasP(){



}



public String getCordNort() {
    return CordNort;
}


public void setCordNort(String cordNort) {
    CordNort = cordNort;
}


public String getCordSurr() {
    return CordSurr;
}


public void setCordSurr(String cordSurr) {
    CordSurr = cordSurr;
}



}
```

mi modelo :

```
public static  String addMoreDetails(List<CoordenadasP> cords) throws Exception
{  
    try
    {

        Connection con=Coneccion.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("insert into Coordenadass (CodN,CodS) values(?,?);");

     for(CoordenadasP cord : cords) {
         ps.setString(1, cord.getCordNort());
         ps.setString(2, cord.getCordSurr());

         ps.addBatch();
    }
    int counts[] = ps.executeBatch();
    if ( counts.length == cords.size() )
        return "someMEssage";
    else
        return null; 
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
    return ex.toString();
   }
}
```

mi action :

```
public class ActionCoordenadass extends ActionSupport{


private ArrayList <CoordenadasP>  cords;



public ArrayList<CoordenadasP> getCords() {
    return cords;
}



public void setCords(ArrayList<CoordenadasP> cords) {
    this.cords = cords;
}



public String inserCord() throws Exception{
    ModelCoordenaP ad = new ModelCoordenaP();
    ModelCoordenaP.addMoreDetails(cords);

    return SUCCESS;

}
```

y finalmente mi jsp :

```
</head>
    <body>
<s:form role="form" action="inserCord" method="POST">
               <table>
<tr>
    <td width="10%">Reg X:</td>
    <td width="15%" >Reg Y :</td>

</tr>
  <tr>
     <td  width="30%" ><input  type="text" name="details.CordNort" /></td>

    <td  width="30%" ><input  type="text" name="details.CordSurr"  /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td  width="30%"><input type="text" name="details.CordNort"  ></td>
  <td  width="30%"><input type="text" name="details.CordSurr"  ></td> 
  </tr>
<tr>
 <td  width="30%"><input type="text" name="details.CordNort"  ></td>
  <td  width="30%"><input type="text" name="details.CordSurr" ></td>
</tr>
</table>
              <div class="box-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">SAVE</button>
              </div> 
            </s:form>
     <s:form role="form" action="consulta" method="POST"> 
              <div class="box-footer">
                <button href="#" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">RETURN!</button>
              </div>
      </s:form>
```

No se lo que estoy haciendo mal,de antemano muchas gracias!

Comment: Necesitas usar el tag `<s:input>` de Struts. El tag normal de html `<input>` no te va a funcionar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En Struts2 puedes usar el tag `<s:textfield label="Username" name="username" />` de la siguiente forma:

```
<s:textfield label="Coord X:" name="cords[0].cordNort"/>
```

Varias cosas están mal en tu código. Te sugiero que empieces sin el arreglo con un objecto de coordenadas simple y un vez que eso funcione puedes aprender a usar los arreglos en struts.

Por convención: los accesores en tu acción (get y set) se escriben en "lower Camel Case" `getCords()[0].getCordNort()`. Cuando los usas en tu JSP struts automáticamente quita o pone el `get` (o el `set`) y cambia mayúsculas y minúsculas iniciales y los interpreta cómo: `cords[0].cordNort`